# Check if email is verified in ionic and firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

After a user login , I want to check if the email used by the user is verified.
I used to do it like this.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
verified=false;
if(firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified){
 this.verified=true;
}else ...
```

But now `firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified` is not working anymore.
I check if the email is verified after the login because maybe the user did not verify his email on signup.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
const autur = firebase.auth();
    autur.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      const veri = user.emailVerified;
      if (veri) {
        // do something
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , but it is not working.

Comment: it is giving me an error. "auth() does not exist on type 'typeof import node_modules/firebase/index'"

Comment: I read in the documentation of ionic that auth() and emailVerified are deprecated now.

Comment: I found the answer to this problem